# Detect what antivirus installed on Windows Operating system

Tags: antivirus, end-points

If we want to detect all Antivirus/Endpoint protection currently installed on a Windows machine?
What is the best approach?
Is there a list of registry locations we can read/iterate? Industry standards?
We see each vendor has its own logic, but maybe there is a unified solution?

We can gather a list of all antivirus and check each on registry, loaded module, folder on program files, etc.. but maybe better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general methods, and I can only suggest you use whichever is within your reach. There is no standard, and some businesses want supported solutions while others prefer their employees to do the work themselves.

### Enterprise

The automated solution is the easiest way. Excluding small businesses, many organizations already have reporting infrastructure in place.

You can pull a software inventory or a custom report from your endpoint management application. This could be their own solution, Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager (formerly known as SCCM), or a competitor such as Altiris or BigFix.

### Code

Manually, you could query WMI using a variety of methods. Command prompt, PowerShell, C++, etc.

You'll want to look at the [root\SecurityCenter2 namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/188861/wmi-34rootsecuritycenter234-c-documentation.html). There is a class where security software is registered. I expect most modern antivirus products will populate here, but there may be exceptions.

You can query WMI using the method of your choice. As an example, in PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct  -ComputerName $computername
```

In case you are not familiar with PowerShell, the "-Computername $computername" part is optional. You can use it to specify a remote host by replacing the $computername variable with a hostname. It will run against the local host if omitted.

Any objects returned from that query should have a **displayName** property that identifies the antivirus product. This includes Windows Defender.

In addition, there will be a **productState** property that indicates its status; a value of 397312 corresponds to "active and up to date" for AV products that follow Microsoft's convention. There is only one third-party AV product I can check at the moment, but it does follow the convention.

Comment: This is not good for Windows Servers :(